# Symfony The security context contains no authentication token

Tags: symfony, security, ezpublish, ezplatform

I get the message

> The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

When my page try to load my assets (css/js/...). But I have not in my web page. My symfony install is under the proxypass /foo

So my URL is http://example.com/foo and my assets are loaded from URL http://example.com/foo/css/...

My page http://example.com/foo/bar works fine but without CSS because http://example.com/foo/css/main.css give me the error above...

Here are my security rules

```
# security.yml
security:
    providers:
        ezpublish:
            id: ezpublish.security.user_provider
#        in_memory:
#            memory: ~
#
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    ezpublish_setup:
        pattern: ^/ezsetup
        security: false

    ezpublish_rest:
        pattern: ^/api/ezp/v2
        stateless: true
        ezpublish_http_basic:
            realm: eZ Publish REST API

    ezpublish_front:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            require_previous_session: false
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout: ~

    default:
        anonymous: ~
```

I've tried to add this lines between `dev` and `ezpublish_setup`

```
dev2:
    pattern: ^/foo/(css|images|js)/
    security: false
```

Same error.

I only have this error in prod environment. Everything works fine in dev environment...

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: looks like you have wrong indent in line 4, `ezpublish` should be child of `firewall`

Comment: Yes, bad copy past from my IDE to stackoverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with

```
dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|foo/css|foo/images|foo/js)
```